# PHP and SQL, selecting the day using dayname()

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select the day (e.g Monday) of a date from a table by using `dayname`.
I queried SELECT dayname(date) from table and the results where fine. Now I am trying to retrieve it in a PHP file.

The code below does not show any errors but the result is empty. 
I am assuming the issue is `echo $data->date." ";`, as I am not selecting date but dayname(date). 
I tried other variations, nothing works. Am I on the right track?

```
$command = "SELECT dayname(date) from table;";
if ($result = $db->query($command)) {
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo $data->date." ";   
}
$result->free()
}
```

Comment: try to add an alias `dayname(date) AS date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it an alias will solve your problem, I suppose.

```
$command = "SELECT dayname(date) AS date FROM table;";
if ($result = $db->query($command)) {
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo $data->date." ";   
}
    $result->free()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$command = "SELECT dayname(date) AS date FROM table;";
if ($result = $db->query($command)) {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $data->date." ";   
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

Without the alias the column would be named `dayname(date)` not `date`.  Using an alias ensures the column name.